# Ruby and Savon Error: POST method not supported by this URL

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

I am a newbie to savon and SOAP.

I am trying to create a request to netsuite wsdl service. When I run it, I get the following error:

```
    D, [2012-02-23T15:05:08.714815 #2284] DEBUG -- : HTTPI executes HTTP POST using the httpclient adapter
    D, [2012-02-23T15:05:19.670815 #2284] DEBUG -- : SOAP response (status 405):
    c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/savon-0.9.9/lib/savon/soap/response.rb:107:in 
    `raise_errors': HTTP error (405): HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL 
    (Savon::HTTP::Error)
```

It seems that I need to use a get instead of post, but I cannot figure out how to set up the request to be a get. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    client = Savon::Client.new do
      wsdl.endpoint = "https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2011_2_0"
      wsdl.namespace = "urn:messages_2011_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
      wsdl.namespace = "urn:core_2011_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
    end

    response = client.request(:body ) do
      soap.element_form_default = :qualified
      soap.body = {"urn:login" =>
                    {
                      "urn:passport" =>
                      {
                        "urnl:email" => "foo@bar.com",
                        "urnl:password" => "foobar123",
                        "urnl:account" => "12345"
                      }
                    }
                  }
    end
```

below is the soap request as seen in SOAPUi

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"         xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2011_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"                         xmlns:urn1="urn:core_2011_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <urn:partnerInfo>      </urn:partnerInfo>
          <urn:applicationInfo>       </urn:applicationInfo>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:login>
             <urn:passport>
                <urn1:email>foo@bar.com</urn1:email>
                <urn1:password>foobar123</urn1:password>
                <urn1:account>12345</urn1:account>
             </urn:passport>
          </urn:login>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're code is almost correct. I changed the SOAP endpoint, specified the urn1 namespace within the request block and moved the SOAP action from the request body Hash to the request method.

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.endpoint = "https://webservices.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2011_2"
  wsdl.namespace = "urn:messages_2011_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
end

response = client.request(:urn, :login) do
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:urn1"] = "urn:core_2011_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
  soap.body = {
    "urn1:passport" => {
      "urn1:email" => "foo@bar.com",
      "urn1:password" => "foobar123",
      "urn1:account" => "12345"
    }
  }
end
```

Hope that helps!

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks daniel, this got me going. Also didn't notice I used urnl instead of urn1, that was a numeral one not the letter L at the end.

Comment: If you are trying to work with the NetSuite SOAP API (SuiteTalk) you might want to check out the [netsuite gem](https://github.com/revolutionprep/netsuite) which handles all the savon stuff for you and has models for the different NetSuite objects.